# The term 'Get-CMApplication' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: windows, powershell, package-managers

I am running `Get-CMApplication` command in powershell on Windows 10. But I get above error. I tried various guides. They all point to `C:\Program Files(x86)` which does not exist in my system. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `C:\Program Files(x86)` MUST exist if you're running Windows 64bit. If it doesn't exist then you;re runing 32bit and the equivalent is simply `C:\Program Files`

Comment: Thanks ! you have solved half my problem. But I cannot find the described files in it : !
I just want to run the `Get-CMApplication` in powershell.

Comment: Because it isn't present in a default Windows installation. You need to load the powershell module for Configuration Manager. You need to install Config manager on your PC and the module will be in the specified folder

Comment: [Install Config Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/servers/deploy/install/install-consoles) says _"The Configuration Manager console is always installed on the site server"_ But I do not have any site server & do not want to host any website. Then how can I install Config Manager

Comment: You can install the console on your PC seperately. Google is your friend. https://www.prajwaldesai.com/install-sccm-console-windows-10/

Comment: Looks Configuration Manager is a paid tool. I will have to find another way. Anyways, I am highly thankful to you :')